# No module named 'charset_normalizer.md__mypyc'

Tags: pyinstaller

I'm using PyInstaller to compile a program and keep coming across the error "No module named 'charset_normalizer.md__mypyc.'" The Charset-Normalizer package is installed.

As a test, I tried re-compiling a program that I had previously created in early September without issue, but now receive the same error. I thought that maybe there is an issue with the versions of either PyInstaller or Charset-Normalizer so I've experimented with different versions, but cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 14):

You are probably missing the "chardet" library
I installed it and it worked.

```
pip install chardet
```

Comment: Your comment says "Charted" but your code sample says "Chardet" I assume one is correct and the other is not?

Comment: Chardet is LGPL, so bundling it with pyinstaller means you should release the source code of your app. charset-normalizer is not LGPL and replaces chardet, so there's a good reason not to install chardet.

Answer (score 7):

I had the EXACT problem. Scripts that I was able to make into executables using Pyinstaller before I could no longer do so again. In my script I used the pdfplumber package, which when you install it also installs other packages like pillow, wand, charset-normalizer, etc.

Since the error was regarding charset-normalizer for me as well, I tried different versions of it. For me it was version 2.1.0 that made the executable work again. Install it with the "pip install charset-normalizer==2.1.0" command: https://pypi.org/project/charset-normalizer/2.1.0/.

If it does not work, go to "Release history" on that link and try another version. Try to remember when was the last time you created a working executable and get the version you think will work for you.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

I just added

```
from charset_normalizer import md__mypyc
```

to the top of my python script.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58449206/20576777

If you don't have the charset-normalizer library installed, then you should install it using the following command:

```
pip install charset-normalizer
```

Comment: I used this import statement to fix my build with nuitka as well

Answer (score 3):

Pyinstaller may sometimes miss your dependency. In such a case run pyinstaller with the `--collect-all` option.
In this case `--collect-all charset_normalizer` should force pyinstaller to include the dependency.

Answer (score 2):

This error [is expected](https://github.com/Ousret/charset_normalizer/issues/253) because of the way pyinstaller works.

To fix it, pass the pyinstaller CLI flag: `--hidden-import charset_normalizer.md__mypyc`

Or, if using SPEC file, set the `hiddenimports` param passed to `Analysis`:

```py
     a = Analysis(['minimal.py'],
         pathex=['/Developer/PItests/minimal'],
         binaries=None,
         datas=None,
         hiddenimports=["charset_normalizer.md__mypyc"],
         hookspath=None,
         runtime_hooks=None,
         excludes=None,
         cipher=block_cipher)
```

---

See https://github.com/Ousret/charset_normalizer/blob/master/docs/community/faq.rst#i-cant-build-standalone-executable for more context.

Answer (score 1):

I have already installed *chardet* and *charset-normalizer*, but I still had the problem. Then I saw this [Github issue](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/21858). As suggested by **IsraelAbebe**, I solved the problem by

```
python -m pip install charset-normalizer==2.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by installing older versions of PyInstaller and Charest-Normalizer. Anytime this messages pops-up, consider installing an older version of the package.